# Android Button - Go back to previous Page

Tags: android, html, button, webview

At the moment I have 3 pages in my app. The 2nd page contains a `webView` and an Android Button to go back to the first page.

In the `webView` on the 2nd page, I use the following line of code to navigate to the 3rd page.

```
window.location.href = "deals.html?subCategoryId=" + subCategoryId;
```

The 3rd page, in terms of layout, is identical to the 2nd page. It contains a webView and the same Android button. However, I would like the `Button` on the 3rd page to send the user back to the 2nd page, not the 1st... Is there a way I can achieve this??

Also, if I press the back button on my phone it always navigates me to the 1st page. Is there a way to change this too?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: I didn't get the context that what do you mean by page? is that Activity?

Comment: Hi Akhilesh, yes. The first two pages are Activities. In the second Activity I use `window.location.href `.

Comment: So you meant, there are 2 `Activity`. Inside the 2nd activity, there is a `WebView` where you open a **webpage** (i.e. 3rd page)?

Comment: Hi antimo, yes, that is what I meant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up using the following to achieve what I wanted:

```
public void goToMainActivity(View   v)  {
    if (webView.canGoBack()){
        webView.goBack();
    }
    else{
        myIntent =  new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);   
        startActivity(myIntent);            
    }
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

call finish() on button click event.

Answer (score 0):

you can modify back button functionality and tell it go to a certain page when the user presses the back button.

```
boolean flag = false;
public void onBackPressed() {
        if(!flag){
            flag = true;
        }
        else{    
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.SecondPage);
            startActivity(intent);
        } 
    }
```

Comment: Hi Daniel, but wouldn't this change the Button on the second page too? Because the same button from the second page is being shown in the third page.

Comment: you can set a flag... if the button clicked once set the flag to true. and put the condition in your OnBackPressed.

Comment: in this way the backbutton skips the first time you hit it.

Comment: Thanks Daniel, this seems to be on the right track. However, if i went from the second page to the first page, the flag would be set to `true`. If I then returned to the second page, the back button would no longer navigate anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

As far as my knowledge goes,,,, you should use a code

```
webview.goBack();
```

this code,will navigate you back to the previous web search

Comment: Thanks Akhilesh. I ended up using a combination of yours and Daniel's answer.

Answer (score 0):

here i have provided the navigation buttons

```
public void forward(View view) { //Forward Button
Toast toast=Toast.makeText(this, "Forward", Toast.LENGTH_LONG); 
toast.show();   
mWebView.goForward(); 
}

public void back(View view) { //Back Button
Toast toast=Toast.makeText(this, "Back", Toast.LENGTH_LONG); 
toast.show();   
mWebView.goBack(); 
}

public void stop(View view) { //Stop Button
Toast toast=Toast.makeText(this, "Stop", Toast.LENGTH_LONG); 
toast.show();   
mWebView.stopLoading(); 
}

public void reload(View view) { //Reload Button
Toast toast=Toast.makeText(this, "Reloading..", Toast.LENGTH_LONG); 
toast.show();   
mWebView.reload(); 
}
```